# Redpark's L2-NET not able to connect using Redsocket SDK

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have purchased two Redpark's L2-NET cables and tried to test the basic connectivity using the examples provided in RedSocket SDK but its not able to connect.Can someone help me in understanding the exact process to establish a successful communication between my ipad/iphone and Ethernet port using Lightening to Ethernet cable.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is my iPad IP&subnet and my machine IP&subnet are not matching.